# Jquery fadeIn Failing To Work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I know this may sound like a repetitive question but I can't find the answer on it. I am attempting to fade in a header and it simply is not working. Yet when I try to use the show function it works perfectly fine.

This is the code I am using:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.header h1').fadeIn('5000');
});
```

Like I said before when I put `show` in place of `fadeIn` it works perfectly fine. I honestly don't have a clue as to why it isn't working.

I have `display:none` set onto `.header h1`. The text displays just not in a fadeIn manner. It just displays instantly like the rest of the page. I am using the latest jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the duration as a string it should be numeric or one of the fadin options like `slow, fast, etc`

Try:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.header h1').fadeIn(5000);
});
```

> Durations are given in milliseconds; higher values indicate slower animations, not faster ones. The strings 'fast' and 'slow' can be supplied to indicate durations of 200 and 600 milliseconds, respectively. If any other string is supplied, or if the duration parameter is omitted, the default duration of  400 milliseconds is used.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the '' marks from your fadeIn like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.header h1').fadeIn(5000);
});
```

The issue is that you are sending a string parameter whereas it should be a numeric on to the fadeIn function.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, fadeIn accepts a Number or a String as first argument. The string must be "slow" or "fast". Any other string defaults to 400 milliseconds. So it should work but maybe not as you expect.